# Outlook registry settings not taking effect / refresh Outlook programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook, office-interop, outlook-addin

I'm trying to change Outlooks reminders/toast notifications programmatically to avoid interferences while users are in critical stages of working on my application.

While I know the relevant keys:

```
Outlook\preferences - NewmailDesktopAlerts
Outlook\options\Reminders - Type
```

Changing the setting in Outlook updates the keys and takes effect.
Changing the registry values doesn't take effect.

I'm looking for a way to "HUP" Outlook/cause it to re-read the registry without closing it (and all subsequent windows the user may have opened). Another option would be to automate opening the Options dialog but I haven't succeeded with that either.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook reads there options on startup only. Nothing you can do about that.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I believe this isn't 100% accurate, if you invoke the options dialog (even if not making any changes), and close it, you can clearly see registry keys being read

Comment: If you open the dialog, and don't make any changes - only read.
If you make changes, naturally both :)
(Tested with Process Monitor)

Comment: But the question is whether Outlook sees any of your changes even if it reads the registry keys.